# Efficiently using Acora / Existence of results in iterator?

Tags: python, iterator

- I'm using the acora library in Python to try and search for multiple keywords in multiple strings.
- It has two functions I can use to search: `findall` and `finditer`
- `findall` returns a list of matches, a bit like an regex findall.
- `finditer` returns an iterator, finding the results one by one

> ```
> >>> import acora
> >>> builder = acora.AcoraBuilder('ab', 'bc', 'de') 
> >>> ac = builder.build()
> >>> ac.findall('this-is-my-testing-phrase-which-has-ab-and-bc-and-de')  
> [('ab', 36), ('bc', 43), ('de', 50)]
> ```

- All I want to know is if there is a single match at all. I don't want to waste more processing power seeing if there's anything else like in `findall`. So the fact that *ab* is in there at all is good enough.

Can I find this with the iterator? Just see if theres at most one match?

I'm asking this because I just timed acora vs basic string matching with 2 nested loops and its 4 times slower, which seems ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

Just realized I can basically just loop through the iter object and break as soon as a result comes through.